# ElasticSearch Join Filter: Using subquery results as filter input possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, join, filter, subquery

I have a Use Case where I want to use ElasticSearch for realtime analytics. Within that, I want to be able to calculate some simple affinity scores.

Those are currently defined using the number of transactions a filtered-by-criteria user base performs, compared with the complete user base.

From my understanding, I'd need to do the following:

1. Get the distinct transactions of my filtered user base
2. Query for these transaction (types) in the complete user base
3. Do the calculation (norming etc.)

To get the "distinct transactions" for the filtered user base, I currently use a Terms Filter Query with faceting which returns all terms (transaction types). As far as I understand, I's need to use this result as input of a Terms Filter Query for the second step to be able to receive the result I want.

I read that there's a pull request on GitHub which seems to implement this (https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/pull/3278), but it's not really obvious to me whether this is already usable in a current release or not.

If not, are there some workarounds how I could implement this?

As additional info, here is my sample mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/store/user/_mapping' -d '
{
  "user": {
    "properties": {
      "user_id": { "type": "integer" },
      "gender": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
      "age": { "type": "integer" },
      "age_bracket": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
      "current_city": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
      "relationship_status": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
      "transactions" : {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "t_id": { "type": "integer" },
          "t_oid": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
          "t_name": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
          "tt_id": { "type": "integer" },
          "tt_name": { "type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

So, for my actual desired result for my example Use Case, I'd have the following:

1. My filtered user base would have this example filter: "gender": "male" & "relationship_status": "single". For these, I want to get the distinct transaction types (field "tt_name" of the nested document) and count the number of distinct user_ids.
2. Next, I want to query my complete user base (no filter other than the list of transaction types from 1.) and count the number of distinct user_ids
3. Do the "affinity" calculations

Comment: There's another issue in github referencing this discussion: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/6769

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a link to a runnable example:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/9da6a30fc12c36f90ae39111a08df283b56ec03c

It presumes documents that look like:

```
{ "transaction_type" : "some_transaction", "user_base" : "some_user_base_id" }
```

The query is set to return no results, since aggregations take care of computing the stats you're looking for:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "match_all" : {}
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "distinct_transactions" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "transaction_type",
        "size" : 20
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "by_user_base" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "user_base",
            "size" : 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here's what the result looks like:

```
  "aggregations": {
      "distinct_transactions": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "subscribe",
               "doc_count": 4,
               "by_user_base": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "2",
                        "doc_count": 3
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "1",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "purchase",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "by_user_base": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "1",
                        "doc_count": 2
                     },
                     {
                        "key": "2",
                        "doc_count": 1
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

So, inside of "aggregations", you'll have a list of "distinct_transactions".  The key will be the transaction type, and the doc_count will represent the total transactions by all users.

Inside of each "distinct_transaction", there's "by_user_base", which is another terms agg (nested).  Just like the transactions, the key will represent the user base name (or ID or whatever) and the doc_count will represent that unique user base's # of transactions.

Is that what you were looking to do?  Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks! If I try to run it I receive a "nested: SearchParseException[[transactions][0]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[0]: Parse Failure [No parser for element [aggs]]]" error. Could you please check?

Comment: Is it possible that localhost on sense.qbox.io is a 0.90 ElasticSearch server?

Comment: Tobi, sorry for not clarifying.  The example I provided must run on 1.0.0 or above.  If you're hitting localhost from the sense.qbox.io example, then you'll need to upgrade your local ES to 1.0.0 to use aggregations.

Comment: Ben, could you have a look at my mapping and see if your method would also work with nested documents?

Comment: It definitely works.  Try this:  http://sense.qbox.io/gist/4f398ab81e615d2085a0ffe0601d4ed69db92fa4

Is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: Ben, thanks a lot for your efforts, if I understand this correctly, this only solves step 1) of my Use Case... Or did I miss something?

Comment: Try this: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/d72c25c96d9942868c9cfd47ebf1e805e3345d1f

It should at least cover 1 & 2.  With the addition of the "global" aggregator, it will return the transaction counts across the entire index, while the original agg will still return the counts for each transaction type of the filtered user base.

Comment: Ben, thanks for your effort again. I will need to check your last suggestion later though I'm currently very busy. Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of ElasticSerach, there's the new `significant_terms` aggregation type, which can be used to calculate the affinity scores for my use case in a more simple way.

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_significant_terms_demo.html#_recommending_based_on_statistics

All the to me relevant metrics can then be calculated in one step, which is very nice!